# "Table Does Not Exist" When MySQL is Shutdown

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently I would log into phpMyAdmin and realize that my databases were there, but the tables "do not exist", when indeed they did. I've been working on the tables for the past hour, shut off MySQL, turned it back on, and now they "don't exist".

What is the issue? And why does this happen when MySQL is shut down?

Comment: Did you select the database in question again after restarting MySQL? You can click on the database name or execute the query `USE WhateverYourDatabaseNameIs`.

Comment: Please clarify "do not exist". Any error message? or they are just not visible in the left pane?